# Why I when to want start session in maltego, I mark an error

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

My problem is very simple I just installed maltego on my computer and I wanted to log in or at least give me the option to log in, but it does not allow me because I get the next window.

[image]

I would like to know that this error is due, I am using linux mint as the operating system for the installation of this application.